# Is it possible to not have to replicate code for each iteration of the function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def math():
    x = str('y')
    
    while x == 'y':
        a = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        a = (((4*a)+1)/(a-3))
        b = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        b = (((4*b)+1)/(b-3))
        c = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        c = (((4*c)+1)/(c-3))
        d = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        d = (((4*d)+1)/(d-3))
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
        print(d)
        x == str(input("Would you like to continue"))
    
math()
```

Hello I'm new to programming and I was just casually doing this to make an easy calculator for my homework assignment and I wanted to know instead of replicating the code for each variable if there was a way to do the math one time and just keep reassigning values to the variable for the math. This might be dumb a question and it's not serious or anything I just was curious if there are better way's to do this.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments and suggestions:

```py
def math():
    x = str('y')
```

`'y'` is a string, so there is no need to convert it to a string using `str()`. `x = 'y'` is sufficient.

```
    while x == 'y':
        a = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        a = (((4*a)+1)/(a-3))
        b = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        b = (((4*b)+1)/(b-3))
        c = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        c = (((4*c)+1)/(c-3))
        d = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        d = (((4*d)+1)/(d-3))
```

**DRY** - don't repeat yourself.

Define a function which takes an input and returns the computed results:

```
def compute(n_times):
    results = []  # initialize results, empty list
    for repetition in range(n_times):  # repeat n times
        inp = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        results.append(((4 * inp) + 1) / (inp - 3))  # append result to list
    return results  # return filled list
```

and call this function `n` times:

```
    result_list = compute(4)  # compute() returns a list with results
    for result in result_list:  # iterate through list
        print(result)
```

ask user if they wish to continue:

```
    x == input("Would you like to continue? ")
```

run your function:

```
math()
```

Conclusion:

```py
def compute(n_times):
    results = []  # initialize results, empty list
    for repetition in range(n_times):  # repeat n times
        inp = float(input("Please enter a number: "))
        results.append(((4 * inp) + 1) / (inp - 3))  # append result to list
    return results  # return filled list

def math():
    how_often = 4
    answer = 'y'
    while answer == 'y':
        result_list = compute(how_often)  # compute() returns a list with results
        for result in result_list:  # iterate through list
            print(result)

        answer == input("Would you like to continue? (y/n): ")

math()
```

Comment: @Dolos - please consider upvoting my answer - thanks.